# Optimize code php dynamic inclusions

Tags: php, include

I have the following code I found on the internet, I'm not very good with php but I would have a way to optimize the following code:

```
<?php

    $pages = array(
        "home" => array(
            "title"       => "Title name page",
            "display"     => "home.php",
            "description" => "Description name page",
        ),
        "order" => array(
            "title"       => "Title name page",
            "display"     => "order.php",
            "description" => "Description name page",
        ),
        "contacto" => array(
            "title"       => "Title name page",
            "display"     => "contacto.php",
            "description" => "Description name page",
        ),
        404   => array(
            "title"       => "Page Not Found",
            "display"     => "404.php",
            "description" => "The page you requested was not found!",
        )
    );

    require('config.php');

    if(isset($_GET["page"])) {
        if (isset($pages[$_GET["page"]])) {
            $page           = $_GET["page"];
            $title          = $pages[$page]["title"];
            $display        = $pages[$page]["display"];
            $description    = $pages[$page]["description"];
            include('header.php');
            include($display);
            include('footer.php');

        } else {
            $page           = 404;
            $display        = $pages[$page]["display"];
            $title          = $pages[$page]["title"];
            $description    = $pages[$page]["description"];
            include('header.php');
            include($display);
            include('footer.php');
        }
    } else {
        $page = "home";
        $display        = $pages[$page]["display"];
        $title          = $pages[$page]["title"];
        $description    = $pages[$page]["description"];
        include('header.php');
        include($display);
        include('footer.php');
    }

?>
```

You believe that there is any way to optimize and includes many not use header / footer?

Comment: Do you know what it does?

Comment: But why do you think not including header and/or footer would optimize this code? What do header and footer do that causes you problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least simplify all those if/else to eliminate the duplication

```
if(isset($_GET["page"])) {
    if (isset($pages[$_GET["page"]])) {
        $page = $_GET["page"];
    } else {
        $page = 404;
   }
} else {
    $page = "home";
}

$title       = $pages[$page]["title"];
$display     = $pages[$page]["display"];
$description = $pages[$page]["description"];
include('header.php');
include($display);
include('footer.php');
```